# Using an ORM for domain modifications. Using SQL Views for all read operations. Is this a form of CQRS?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, cqrs

Folks,
I am working on a model where users can choose defaults or enter custom values, the results form a number of population-based projections.

I am drawn to using a [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)-like approach to separate reporting and domain-affecting code.

I intend to use basic SQL views with ADO.NET in one service for reports, and Entity Framework in another service for persisting modifications.

I don't think that event sourcing is required here. Reporting will be done against the domain database.

Is the above an example of CQRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully CQRS but it is a good practices from CQRS to bring into your DDD solution, i blogged exactly about this topic with example [here](http://moh-abed.com/2011/09/13/pure-old-ddd-with-a-twist-from-cqrs/)

You take the concept of separating read from write model to make ur domain more solid, but without the complexity of separating database and event storage.

Comment: Separating Read from Write Model is the exact definition of CQRS, which has nothing to do with persistence mechanisms. Event Sourcing is another pattern, often promoted/used in combination with CQRS.

Comment: You are right but the thing is they stress the idea of separating the data to create one de-normalized data store for query and another which is normalized if relational or message store.

Comment: I do not quite agree with "It is not fully CQRS" i think it is CQRS, Check this [out] ( http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/)

Comment: I have a concern on trying to "sell" this approach to my peers. If I am using ado.net or some microOrm like dapper for the read service, I will need to somehow hardcode strings to the SQL views. How do I justify this, as I know that this will be compared to old school ado/sql programming.

Comment: You dont have to hardcore strings, the technology does not matter .. you can even use nhibernate for the read part as long as you separated the read model from write

Answer (score 5):

It's a basic form, yes. After all, reading and writing are separated, and the responsibilities for each are handled by different services. Moreover, your read service doesn't touch your domain layer, it goes straight from the service layer to the ORM. That is definitely the basis of CQRS.

Event Sourcing is actually not a part of CQRS. The two practices are often combined, though.